PostgreSQL ODBC Driver
Seeking guidance on a commercial ODBC driver that supports bulk inserts into a PostgreSQL target. The readily available driver works for small data sets but performs row by row inserts so it doesn't work for very large data sets. I've tried all sorts of configurations of the readily available driver and cannot get it to support bulk inserts.
I've already tried numerous configurations of the readily available ODBC driver.

Have you tried using COPY?
